# Django backend, reactjs frontend - How do I pass context variable from views.py to app.js?

Tags: reactjs, django, dictionary, render

I'm creating an application that webscrapes data. I've created all my logic in the Django backend and it works perfectly fine. I put the variables needed into a dictionary to be rendered out.

**views.py**

```
return render(request, 'index.html', context_dict)
```

It properly renders out to my index.html, I am able to see the variable. However I need these *context_dict* variables to render out to my **app.js** file, so I can use it with react on the frontend. Please let me know how this is possible. Thanks in advance!

**index.html**

```
{{ context_dict }} ### renders here properly, but need in app.js instead ###
```

**app.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <div className="center-column">
        <div className="item-row">
          <div class="centered">
            <span> - - - - NEED TO CALL MY CONTEXT_DICT HERE! - - - - </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
   </div>    
  );
}



export default App;
```

Local Server - **127.0.0.0.1:8000**
[image: 127.0.0.0.1:8000]

Comment: these variables are not exposed to frontend. when you render a template with some variables it transpiles any variables and/or logic to html and send back to front. when you need to consume data from backside to your frontside, you would create GET endpoints that you call at your front and your back responds with JSON value

Comment: @buzzato Thanks for your direction and explanation! I will look up how to create the GET endpoints

Comment: just to piggyback on what @buzatto said, it's not only GET. It could be POST, PATCH, or PUT if your will be using react for frontend and django for backend. Simply put, you need a REST framework such as [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to allow such communication between your backend and frontend.